# Google Cloud Error (The requested URL / was not found on this server)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to create a sample php web application but it is showing error: The requested url / is not found, when deployed through google cloud.The files includes maingame.php,app.yaml,data_file.txt(one sample file)

My app.yaml looks like this:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /maingame.php
  script: maingame.php
```

My Error on website is:

Error: Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Comment: The error message looks correct to me. What is your specific question here? If it is: Why do I get the error, then please re-read the error message: No resource is found for the requested URL.  Request `http://example.com/maingame.php` instead.

Comment: Thanx for commenting.How can i get into that site by just typing http://example.com.

Comment: Please read through the as duplicated linked Q&A, it should offer some options depending on what you would like to do in the end. I also strongly believe that the product documentation shows how that can be done.